# Any way to hide list views on Community

Tags: community

Our org has over 50+ list views used for various things. I've created a Community page where I'd like to only show two lists: My Service Hub Cases and All Service Hub Cases.

Using the Full Record List Component, when a user selects the dropdown, they see all the lists they have access to.  I'm asking if it's possible to only show specific lists here (maybe even using CSS?) instead of all lists available?

I cannot go and update the visibility on 50+ other lists because they do not belong to my project.

[image: record List view Component in Community page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as a List View is shared with the Portal/Community Users, there's no way to hide those if you are using standard out of the box components.

Your option here could be to customize the page your are on and utilize [`lightning:listView`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation) if you are building using aura components.